# Pass String variable in @XmlAttribute name tag

Tags: java, xml, xml-attribute

My requirement is i have to set  @XmlAttribute name dynamically.

```
String nameValue="code";

@XmlAttribute(name = nameValue) //unable to set String Variable as name param
protected String value;
```

`The value for annotation attribute XmlAttribute.name must be a constant expression`
 is there any way to send  @XmlAttribute name param dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried public static final String nameValue="code";

Comment: yes.. static also not working..

Comment: As the error message said: `must be a constant expression`. You can not put a variable name in it.

Comment: ok name param require constant value.. is there any way to send name param dynamically...